# Executing a Batch file on a Azure Virtual Machine from outside the VM

Tags: azure, function, batch-file, azure-data-factory, virtual-machine

I want to run this batch file on a schedule or from a trigger from outside the VM.

How can I do this? From my Azure portal I've tried Azure Functions and Azure Logic Apps but I have not found a straightforward way to run the script.

Comment: The simplest way is to use task scheduler if the VM is Windows, or crontab if it's Linux

Comment: You can run the commands from Azure Run Command" that allows you to execute scripts on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Task scheduler to run the task.

1. Enable PowerShell Remoting on the VM:

   `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`
2. Identify VM IP Address or Hostname
3. Run the Batch File Remotely
4. Establish Remote Session:

   `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName VMHostname -Credential (Get-Credential)`

Here instead of getting cred, you can use service principal or any other method for login

5. Navigate to Batch File Location:

   `cd C:\Path\To\Batch\File\Location`
6. Run the Batch File:

   `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { .\YourBatchFile.bat }`